# Problem executing a .bat file at a path where folder name has spaces, in VB6

Tags: vb6, shellexecute, filepath

I'm trying to execute a .bat file in VB6 (silent window mode) with following code.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

cmds = WshShell.RUN("E:\My Folder\RunScript.bat", 0, True)

Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Things work absolutely fine if there's no space in `'My Folder'`.but call fails if such a space is encountered. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
cmds = WshShell.RUN("""E:\My Folder\RunScript.bat\""", 0, True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about WSH, but try adding single quotes:

```
cmds = WshShell.RUN("'E:\My Folder\RunScript.bat'", 0, True)
```

They may do the trick if RUN passes the command on to some other instance.

Alternatively, if you want to go the ugly route, you could try finding out the 8.3 name of the directory (using `dir`), and specify that.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
cmds = WshShell.RUN("""E:\My Folder\RunScript.bat""", 0, True)
```

?